# How to get Locust to evenly spread distributions among tasks?

Tags: locust

I have created a locustfile with 28 tasks.
When I run locust it only runs a subset of the tasks.
Here is the command I am using:

```
locust -f $locustfile.py --headless -u 5 -r 1 --run-time 15m --logfile locust.log
```

I am running it for 15 minutes and each task takes just a few seconds to a minute to run.
Upon completion, it says that it ran a task 187 times yet only 8 of the 28 tasks were run.
Of the 8 it did run it ran them anywhere from 17 to 31 times.

I'm decorating all of the tasks with "@task" so they should all be weighted the same.
Can anyone tell me why the task selection is so limited and how to make it spread out more?

Comment: have you tried master/nodes mode(distribution)?

Comment: I have not tried master/worker yet.  But I should progress to that in a few days.

Comment: Is it always the same number of tasks that are run? Or always the same tasks? Have you tried running each task individually as the only one marked with `@task` to make sure that Locust can run it? Did you check the `Exceptions` to see if your code was broken somehow?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I had a bug in my error event handling that was causing the failures not to be reported.  I fixed this and am now getting all of the test results.  It was Solowalker's comment that led me to this discovery.